# Speed up PNG++ when converting raw mono8 data to PNG

Tags: c++, image, arm, libpng

I need help using PNG++ to execute an optimized conversion of a camera buffer image (in raw mono8 data) to a png compression less file. The following works, but it's too slow. I'm going to execute it in ARM. I need a really fast process.

```
    sprintf(mBuffer, "%lu.png", pFrame->FrameCount);
    try
    {
        //Take the image from my camera buffer and put it into  vector i can 
        //work with 
        images = (const unsigned char*)pFrame->ImageBuffer;

        //create the png profile to be used
        png::image< png::gray_pixel > image(1024,1024); 

        //Take every byte from the vector and put in the determined position on 
        //the image matrix
        for(int i=0;i<1024;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<1024;j++)
            {
                png::gray_pixel pix = images[i*1024+j];
                        image[i][j] = pix;
            }
        }

            image.write(mBuffer);
    }
    catch (std::exception const& error)
        {
            std::cerr << "Teste: " << error.what() << std::endl;

    }
```

Comment: I am not familiar with png::gray_pixel, but I think you may be just copying memory byte by byte, and if possible it would be better to do it in chunks that much the width of your CPU's data bus, i.e. 64-bit or 32-bit rather than 8-bit chunks, so I am thinking of using memcpy() and effectively moving 16 64-bit numbers instead of 1024 8-bit numbers. Have a look here http://www.embedded.com/design/configurable-systems/4024961/Optimizing-Memcpy-improves-speed

Comment: as suggested, use memcpy instead of doing the copy yourself. also improve the question. it isn't clear what you have tried.

Comment: "png compression less file" == a not-too-much compressed file? It's possible (likely, even) your library handles compression automatically. Check if there is a function to influence its parameters -- surely there should be a choice between "fast" and "good". Another option may be to handle the entire PNG-creating stuff yourself, thus removing *all* library overhead. Creating "worst-compressed-ever" zlib data is a case of injecting a few bytes into the raw, otherwise uncompressed, data stream. You may have to test what's better: compressing in memory or creating a larger file and writing that.

Comment: You can not use `memcpy()`, if this is a C++ template class which has modified the accessors.  PNG is just a header with *zlib*.  I agree with Jongware that the compression level will be the determinate.  Simply compressing the original `image` data and avoiding the `png::image<>` template class will make things faster.  It is about 2MBbytes of data.

Answer (score 0):

This may, or may not help - it is just a suggestion. If your framebuffer is a sequential load of 8-bit unsigned pixels, that is the exact same format as a NetPBM Portable Greymap (PGM) of type P5 which is documented [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_graymap). This can be written very quickly and can be used in webpages directly, or can be readily converted into a `png` using ImageMagick ([here](http://www.imagemagick.org)) like this:

```
convert image.pgm image.png
```

Then your image writing could be simple like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define HEIGHT  100
#define WIDTH   256

int main(){

   FILE *imageFile;
   uint8_t image[HEIGHT][WIDTH];
   int x,y,pixel;

   /* Create a greyscale ramp - you don't need this, you would use your framebuffer */
   for(x=0;x<HEIGHT;x++){
      for(y=0;y<WIDTH;y++){
         image[x][y]=y;
      }
   }

   /* Now write to a file */
   imageFile=fopen("image.pgm","wb");
   if(imageFile==NULL){
      perror("ERROR: Cannot open output file");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   /* You could coalesce the next 3 lines into a single fprintf() if you wanted */
   fprintf(imageFile,"P5\n");           // P5 filetype
   fprintf(imageFile,"%d %d\n",WIDTH,HEIGHT);   // dimensions
   fprintf(imageFile,"255\n");          // Max pixel

   fwrite(image,HEIGHT,WIDTH,imageFile);

   fclose(imageFile);
}
```

Depending on what you actually want to do with the images, you could maybe batch convert them when you are finished your high-speed acquisition run, or convert them in the background later, or somewhere else on a different machine altogether.

In my example, I create the image, but you already have yours in the frame buffer, so your image writing would become:

```
imageFile=fopen("image.pgm","wb");
fprintf(imageFile,"P5\n%d %d\n255\n",WIDTH,HEIGHT);
fwrite(images,HEIGHT,WIDTH,imageFile);
close(imageFile);
```

Comment: Neither Firefox nor Chrome handles PGM (P5) images very well.  They offer to download them and invite you to supply a viewer.  So while I agree that writing to P5 is simple (it's what I usually do), you should finish up by converting to PNG before putting the image on a web page.